VS Code Extension For Language Support Only Highlighting Lowercase syntax (want to use uppercase)
I've been working on a new vs code exention for MEL (Medical Expression Lanaguage) and I'm running into some issues with it not working with uppercase Syntax. Most of the existing code has uppercase syntax and I would love to be able to copy and paste it into vs code and have syntax highlighting. I've been creating an extension to do just that but I'm running into an issue where is it is highlighting the syntax but only if it is completely lowercase. Here are my yo code files:
mel.tmLanguage.json
{
    "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martinring/tmlanguage/master/tmlanguage.json",
    "name": "Mel",
    "patterns": [
        {
            "include": "#keywords"
        },
        {
            "include": "#strings"
        }
    ],
    "repository": {
        "keywords": {
            "patterns": [{
                "name": "keyword.control.mel",
                "match": "/\b(IF|if|then|THEN|ELSE|else|EndIf|ENDIF|FOR|for|COND|cond|CASE|case|ENDCOND|endcond|EndFor|ENDFOR|While|while|endWhile|ENDWHILE|Do|do)\b/"
            }]
        },
        "strings": {
            "name": "string.quoted.double.mel",
            "begin": "\"",
            "end": "\"",
            "patterns": [
                {
                    "name": "constant.character.escape.mel",
                    "match": "\\\\."
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "scopeName": "source.mel"
}


package.json
{
  "name": "mel",
  "displayName": "MEL Language Support",
  "description": "Medical Expression Language Support",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.89.0"
  },
  "categories": [
    "Programming Languages"
  ],
  "contributes": {
    "languages": [{
      "id": "mel",
      "aliases": ["Mel", "mel"],
      "extensions": [".mel"],
      "configuration": "./language-configuration.json"
    }],
    "grammars": [{
      "language": "mel",
      "scopeName": "source.mel",
      "path": "./syntaxes/mel.tmLanguage.json"
    }]
  }
}

Any suggestions will be helpful, I'm honestly completely stuck and not sure why this isn't working. thank you in advance :) If you need any other files just lmk please.

I'm not sure how you got it working with only lowercase letters.
My guess is that you were testing it with an old version of your grammar.
JSON TextMate regex's don't need to be surrounded with forward slashes /.
JSON requires backslashes \ to be escaped with backslashes \\.
So your \b is actually the ascii code , BackSpace.
If you are wanting it to be completely case insensitive, you can place (?i) at the start of the regex.
\\b(IF|if|then|THEN|ELSE|else|EndIf|ENDIF|FOR|for|COND|cond|CASE|case|ENDCOND|endcond|EndFor|ENDFOR|While|while|endWhile|ENDWHILE|Do|do)\\b

